# Help me identify this Batman set

Tags: set-identification

I've tried to look up what I thought were specific bricks without luck, so please help me. I know it's a Batman set, but not much more. The red shield is #17979, its red transparent. There is a hook behind with #24144 and a "bat-rang" #26-01

[image: Batman set]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did new research on Rebrickable and found out it is **[#76086 - Knightcrawler Tunnel Attack](https://rebrickable.com/sets/76086-1/knightcrawler-tunnel-attack/)**